# Does it make sense to cache and read from it when I'm sure I will have to read some data from DB?

Tags: mysql, caching, redis, memcached

A DB currently has a table **some_table**:

```
conn_id     data
id1 - - - - - a
id1 - - - - - b
id2 - - - - - c
id3 - - - - - d
```

Now my code has to do this:

```
do_something([id1,id2,id3,id4])
```

I currently do a MySQL query:

```
select * from some_table where conn_id in (id1, id2, id3, id4);
```

and generate this:

```
{
  id1 => [a,b],
  id2 => [c],
  id3 => [d]
}
```

If I was to cache this data, the next time I do this, I will find the keys for id1,id2 and id3 in the cache.  However since id4 does not exist in the cache nor DB, I will always have to query the DB.

**Does it make sense to cache this data?**

I can get data for id1, id2, id3 from the cache.  But for id4 I will do a MySQL query:

```
select * from some_table where id in (id4)
```

Which one would be more performant?  At a time, I can have 200 id's in the request (do_something) out of which any number can be non existent.

Answer (score 0):

Things to clarify

1. When you do caching. You have to make sure that the data in your cache is in perfect sync with primary data source (DB).
2. If data is changed in DB you need invalidate the cache

Now to answer the question

Warm up your cache for the 1st time using select * query.
After that for each insert or update to your DB handle them in your cache too. So that you can avoid querying DB for consecutive selects